# Failure to upload with curl in PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, ssh, upload

I want to use curl in ssh with PHP and I did it, but program sometimes does not work in PHP.

I run this in ssh and it worked successfully:

```
curl -F video=@123.mp4 "https://example.com"
```

But when I write this code in PHP it is uploaded it but does not complete:

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('ip');
if (!$ssh){
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    $ssh->login('username','password') or die("Login failed");
    $ssh->exec('curl -F video=@123.mp4 "https://example.com"');
}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [ssh2](http://php.net/ssh2) functions. Anything you'd do via an `exec()` call can be done directly using these functions, saving you a lot of connections and shell invocations.

Example:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'curl -F video=@123.mp4 "https://example.com"');
```

Are you trying to upload the larger file? because PHP might be timed out while uploading the file. I suggest you try with smaller file in few KB, if that works then confirm that code works fine, then you should increase the timeout `set_time_limit(0)` and run the code

Comment: Thanks But I did it, and I still have problem :(

Comment: Are you trying to upload the larger file? because PHP might be timed out while uploading the file. I suggest you try with smaller file in few KB, if that works then confirm that code works fine, then you should increase the timeout `set_time_limit(0)` and run the code